# How come I see POST data when using CURL but not when I open the .php page in a web browser?

Tags: php, json, curl, post

when I type in the command below I get the results from POST in the CLI but when I open the http://172.16.16.126:8089/Test.php I don't see any of those POST data just the other data.

I know I am missing something here right? Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"saad","password":"something","Hello":"Hey"}' http://172.16.16.126:8089/Test.php

stdClass Object
(
    [username] => saad
    [password] => something
    [Hello] => Hey
)
<pre>
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => John
    [age] => 42
)
Name: John Age: 42

JSON data: {"name":"John","age":42}

stdClass Object
(
    [name] => John
    [age] => 42
)
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [age] => 42
)
Name: John Age: 42
```

---

```
Test.php
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  print_r($data);
}

echo "<pre>\n";

$data = (object) array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 42
);

print_r($data);

printf("Name: %s Age: %s\n\n", $data->name, $data->age);

$data = json_encode($data);

echo "JSON data: $data\n\n";

$data = json_decode($data);

print_r($data);

$data = (array) $data; // cast (convert) the object to an array

print_r($data);

printf("Name: %s Age: %s\n\n", $data['name'], $data['age']);

?>
```

Comment: ...because the command below is posting and when you visit the page you're getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you request the URL that is handled by the PHP program, you run the PHP program.

That program looks at the input from the request and then generates a response based on it.

If you make one request with cURL that includes a JSON body, and then another request from the browser which does not, then you will get different responses for each of them.

---

You *could* write your PHP program so that when it gets a POST request with a JSON body, it saves the data somewhere (e.g. in a database), and then when it gets a GET request (which could be the result of someone typing the URL into their browser's address bar) to fetch that data instead of reading the POST body.

That would give you the result you appear to be expecting.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I knew I was doing something wrong with these web request!